# How to cast string to timestamp and then select record..?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table name `mytable` as follow..

```
ID      LOCATION    TIMERECORDED            
45744   20          2017-04-21 19:00:00.000 
45788   55          2017-04-21 19:15:00.000 
45832   55          2017-04-21 19:30:00.000
```

Here `TIMERECORDED` column datatype is varchar

I want to get top record which is inserted within 25 minites
I have written below query

```
select  *
from    mytable t
where   t.location_id = ? and
        t.time_recorded >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - NUMTODSINTERVAL(25,'MINUTE') and
        ROWNUM <= 1
order by t.time_recorded DESC
```

So as `TIMERECORDED` column data is of type `varchar` datatype can I cast to `Timestamp` and then get result..?

**Updates :**

Recently DBA migrated `MSSQL DB to ORACLE` DB but unfortunately in above table ( mytable) column (TIMERECORDED) had datatype `nvarchar`.

As table is having many records what should be solution

1. create new table (mytable) and then insert data into it
2. Is there any way to sort data that convert string to timestamp and
   then
       get result?

Comment: hint: `to_timestamp`

Comment: Hints as answers it's just missing a [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm)

Comment: You can convert a string to a timestamp using the TO_TIMESTAMP function (with the right format model, to match the format in your column). Is the format really NVARCHAR and not NVARCHAR2? If so, you may need a (trivial) cast to NVARCHAR2 first, as TO_TIMESTAMP may or may not accept a NVARCHAR argument. Then: you should definitely fix the data type as soon as you can. You can create a new table and insert data into it, or you can create a new column of data type TIMESTAMP in your existing table, populate it, then delete the NVARCHAR column, and rename the new column to the old column's name.

Comment: This (adding the column to the existing table etc.) will allow existing queries imported from MSSQL DB to work without modification.

Comment: I'm going to be that annoying person and ask the important question: Why in the name of all that's holy is `timerecorded` a `varchar` column when something date/time related is the more useful and obvious data type?

Comment: A separate suggestion: instead of calling a function (`numtodsinterval`), in your case it would be more efficient to use an interval literal (which is not a function):  `interval '25' minute`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  * FROM    
  mytable t
WHERE   
  t.location_id = ? 
 AND
  to_timestamp(t.time_recorded, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - NUMTODSINTERVAL(25,'MINUTE') 
 AND
  ROWNUM <= 1
```

ORDER BY t.time_recorded DESC

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the column value to a timestamp to compare with your last-25-minutes value, but as the strings are in a format that can be compared, you could also convert that target value to a string instead:

```
select *
from (
  select  *
  from    mytable t
  where   t.location_id = ? and
          t.time_recorded >= to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - NUMTODSINTERVAL(25,'MINUTE'),
            'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')
  order by t.time_recorded DESC
)
where ROWNUM <= 1;
```

You need to order the resulsts *before* you apply a rownum filter, so I've put most of your original query into an inline view (subquery), and moved the fownum filter outside that.

With your sample three rows and the ? replaced with 55, the output of that is:

```
        ID LOCATION_ID TIME_RECORDED          
---------- ----------- -----------------------
     45832          55 2017-04-21 19:30:00.000
```

(My local time was actually 19:00 when I ran that, but the filter still works)

As mentioned in comments, and as you already know, ideally you should change the column data type. As @mathguy suggested, you )or your DBA) can add and populate a new column, verify its data is correct, then drop the old column and rename the new one. Quick outline:

```
alter table mytable add (new_time_recorded timestamp);
update mytable set new_time_recorded =
  to_timestamp(time_recorded, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3');
alter table mytable drop (time_recorded);
alter table mytable rename column new_time_recorded to time_recorded;
```

Then you can do a similar query but without the data type conversion:

```
select *
from (
  select  *
  from    mytable t
  where   t.location_id = 55 and
          t.time_recorded >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - NUMTODSINTERVAL(25,'MINUTE')
  order by t.time_recorded DESC
)
where ROWNUM <= 1;

        ID LOCATION_ID TIME_RECORDED               
---------- ----------- ----------------------------
     45832          55 21-APR-17 19.30.00.000000000
```

If the old column was indexed or had any constraints you'll need to recreate those for the new column.

If you describe the table or do `select *` then the new column will be shown last, even if the old one wasn't; but hopefully you don't have any code that assumes or relies on the column order. If you do then you'd have to create a copy of the table instead, with the columns in the order your code expects, which is a bit more work as there may be more side effects - privileges, triggers, etc.

Comment: As I just suggested to the OP in a Comment: in a situation like this, it is more efficient to use an interval literal, `interval '25' minute`, instead of a function (`numtodsinterval`). Similar to using date literals instead of `to_date` and timestamp literals instead of `to_timestamp`.

Comment: @mathguy - as it's only evaluated once I'm not sure the difference will be measurable, but even so, according to the execution plan they're treated the same anyway - `numto*interval()` is shown as an interval literal and `to_timestamp()` is usually shown as a timestamp literal, while a date literal is shown as a `to_date()` call. That conversion still has *some* cost at parse time, of course. However, for a fixed value I would use a literal anyway just for clarity/brevity, I just didn't pay attention to that part of the code in the question *8-)